# Wireshark: looking for specific TCP/IP port, loopback

Tags: wireshark

I want to see loopback TCP traffic in Wireshark(3.0.3), 64-bit Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Npcap(0.995) Then I apply display filter

> loop && tcp.port==9091

or

> loop and tcp.port==9091

Still see all loopback traffic. All ports. Both v4 and v6.
What's wrong? Why I see all?